# Primefaces Tree: click event on node's label when selectionMode='checkbox'

Tags: tree, primefaces

I'm using the primefaces[3.4] showcase with tree and checkbox selection:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeSelectionCheckbox.jsf

Is it possible to attach a p:ajax event for click on node's label??

I need to update a panel with children objects when user click over tree's nodes labels, not necessarily when user select them (click on checkbox).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I workaround this, just adding a checkbox inside the treeNode template and changing the selectionMode to single.

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" cache="false"  
            selectionMode="single"  selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}" id="tree">  

        <p:ajax event="select" update=":form:messages" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeSelect}" />  

        <p:treeNode>  
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="treeCheck" value="#{node.selected}"/> 
            <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />  
        </p:treeNode>  
    </p:tree>
```

Consider that you have to code manually the logic to check/uncheck parent/childs nodes when it should.

Thanks.

Comment: How does your method `onNodeSelect` look like? Is it using a parameter of type `NodeSelectEvent`?

Comment: This workaround does NOT work fine 4 me. I don't think it is possible to get all the selected checkbox´s in the bean of component `treeCheck`

Comment: @jimmybondy yes: public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) and you can get all the selected objects iterating the associated bean list and evaluating the 'selected' property.

Answer (score 2):

You should never have to call the server to do something as simple as showing/hidding other elements on the page. Primefaces should do a better job with this. In the meantime, consider this javascript code...

```
<p:treeNode type="parent" styleClass="parent">
    <h:outputText value="#{myLabel}"/>
</p:treeNode>
```

...

```
<script>
jQuery(".parent > .ui-tree-selectable > .ui-treenode-label").each(function(){
    var label = jQuery(this);

    label.click(function(){
        label.siblings(".ui-tree-toggler").click();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `p:tree` element is capable of handling 4 events:

```
+----------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Event    | Listener Parameter                     | Fired                      |
+----------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| expand   | org.primefaces.event.NodeExpandEvent   | When a node is expanded.   |
| collapse | org.primefaces.event.NodeCollapseEvent | When a node is collapsed.  |
| select   | org.primefaces.event.NodeSelectEvent   | When a node is selected.   |
| unselect | org.primefaces.event.NodeUnselectEvent | When a node is unselected. |
+----------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

The select event is what you want.

**EDIT:** This won't work when using checkboxes in the tree.

Comment: The `select` event will only work (a) if selection mode is `single or (b) in checkbox mode when checkbox is clicked but not the node (e.g. text). So that will not work

Comment: @jimmybondy I cannot believe I overlooked the fact the OP is using checkboxes in the tree. Of course you're right that this won't work so I updated my answer.

Comment: @jimmybondy,siebz0r: thanks a lot for your time. Do you think it's possible to add checkboxes manually as nodes template in PF 3.4 tree? Maybe I could use selection='single' and control the selected nodes by myself. Another idea, would be possible use a <p:commandLink> as node's label to fire an event?

Comment: @vladiastudillo I think the only clean way to do this would be to modify the PrimeFaces source to make the node clickable.